# how to call concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor map with different functions

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have something like this:

```
class Animal:
    def eat(food):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Duck(Animal):
    def eat(food):
        # do something

class Pig(Animal):
    def eat(food):
        # do something

class Cat(Animal):
    def eat(food):
        # do something

class Dog(Animal):
    def eat(food):
        # do something

duck = Duck()
pig = Pig()
cat = Cat()
dog = Dog()
animals = [duck, pig, cat, dog]

food = Candy()
for animal in animals:
    animal.eat(food)
```

Now I want to convert the last 2 lines with multi processing. How can I do that? I was only able to find examples where the function is the same function, not "eat" function of different types of objects.

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()
futures = executor.map(???)
```

Comment: First of all, `map` does not return a `Futures` instance, *but* method `concurrent.futures.Executor.submit` *does* and that is what you want to use multiple times. Read the documentation.

Comment: [(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76466235/how-can-we-pass-psycopg2-connectionpool-object-to-processpoolexecutor-python)]
could you please pint me why i am getting TypeError while using the below code, and how can I use the same with map implementation also.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful when using multiprocessing, since it might behave different on different OS.

As you noted, `map` applies the same function to different items of an iterable. In your case you have to do the other way around:

```py
food = Candy()
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    # start processes
    futures = [executor.submit(animal.eat, food) for animal in animals]
    # wait for all to finish
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
```

Comment: The call to `concurrent.futures.wait(futures)` is actually not necessary since there will be an implicit call to `executor.shutdown(wait=True)` at the termination of the `with ... as executor:` block, which will wait for all pending futures to be done.

Comment: @Booboo: True, Thanks for the edit!