# how can we pass psycopg2 connectionpool object to processpoolexecutor python

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

I have a list of csv file, need to load the data to postgres table.
I tried to use processpoolexecutor and pass connectionpool as parameter to loadcsv function.
Getting error like TypeError while submitting the function.

In wait getting TypeError and program got hanged.
let me know if any one faced the same issue and how to solve the same.

Please let me know any better way to load file faster.

```
def load_csv_file(file_path, connection, semaphore):
    with open(file_path, "r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            try:
                semaphore.acquire()
                connection.cursor().execute(
                    """
                    INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column3)
                    VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
                    """,
                    row,
                )
            finally:
                semaphore.release()
def main():
    # Create a connection pool
    connection_pool = ThreadedConnectionPool(
        max_conn=10,
        host="localhost",
        port=5432,
        dbname="my_database",
        user="my_user",
        password="my_password",
    )

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        # Load the CSV files to the table
        for file_path in ["file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv"]:
            executor.submit(
                load_csv_file,
                file_path,
                connection_pool.getconn(),
                semaphore=semaphore,
            )
```